# searching an unlisted video in my own channel using API C# code

Tags: c#, video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I am trying to search for the unlisted videos which are present in my youtube channel. I tried with the below code, bu I ended up in searching the public videos only.. Unlisted videos were not searched.. Can anyone help with this.

```
        var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
        searchListRequest.Q = "My Video Name"; // Replace with your search term.
        searchListRequest.ChannelId = "My Channel ID";
        searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;


        // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
        var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

        List<string> videos = new List<string>();
        List<string> channels = new List<string>();
        List<string> playlists = new List<string>();

        // Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
        // matching videos, channels, and playlists.
        foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
        {
            switch (searchResult.Id.Kind)
            {
                case "youtube#video":
                    // if (searchResult.Id.VideoId == "pavY4SCQ4uY")             
                    videos.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.VideoId));
                    break;

                case "youtube#channel":
                    channels.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.ChannelId));
                    break;

                case "youtube#playlist":
                    playlists.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.PlaylistId));
                    break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Videos:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", videos)));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Channels:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", channels)));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Playlists:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", playlists)));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get authenticated with OAuth2 to get your own videos.
Also to get videos in a channel use

1) channels.list() method then look for contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads

2) playlistItems.list with that playlistId.

This will result in 2 quotas vs 100 quotas in a search request.

(When you are looking for your own channel instead of channelId, just use mine=true in channels.list method)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are authenticated using Oauth2, and not using a public api key.  You can add forMine to your request and get only your videos back.

> [forMine](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)  Boolean
>  This parameter can only be used in a properly
>   authorized request. The forMine parameter restricts the search to only
>   retrieve videos owned by the authenticated user. If you set this
>   parameter to true, then the type parameter's value must also be set to
>   video.